# install glibc.i386 on x64 centos 6.4

Tags: 64-bit, centos6, i386, cadence-virtuoso

I have CentOS 6.4 x64 but I need a `glibc.i386` to run the Cadence Virtuoso application.

I tried `yum install glibc.i386`
but what I get is "**`No package glibc.i386 available`**."

How can I have this package?

I tried **`yum install glibc`**
but I got this "**`Package glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686 already installed and latest version Nothing to do`**"

but I need `glibc.i386`

Answer (score 0):

Use **yum install glibc** - CentOS will do the rest

Comment: Package glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think `glibc.i386` is not present?

Odds are good `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just needs to be updated to include the 32-bit glibc libraries (and possibly exclude the 64-bit) when you're trying to run Cadence Virtuoso.